# how to access array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

```
    array (size=338)
   '6ada0377-c28b-4df2-adf5-02b813b3214e' => 
     array (size=2)
      'source_catagory' => string 'Exoclick' (length=8)
       'traffic_type' => string 'Adult Popunders - Chrome' (length=24)
   '6ada0377-c28b-http://www.myvidster.com/video/26933' => 
     array (size=2)
      'source_catagory' => string 'Exoclick' (length=8)
      'traffic_type' => string 'Adult Popunders - Chrome' (length=24)
```

I want to access source_category, I hope someone could be of help

Comment: i guess u can use **var_dump()**

Comment: This looks like an already `var_dump()`'ed array..? Care to show the original?

Comment: your question rackons you want to print like this in this way .. please be specific. is this how you want to print ? or you want to get data from 'source_catagory' key ?

Comment: and i guess you already did **var_dump** and now want to get data from **source_category** key .. then foreach will helpful for you ..

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get **source_category** key.

```
array_column($array, 'source_catagory');
```

OR

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['source_catagory'] . '<br />';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpio.net/s/1vp)